# MySQL Create User Operation failed

Tags: mysql, windows, codeigniter

I have been trying to create a MySQL user programmatically.

`$this->db->query('CREATE USER 'agit****'@'localhost'); // Using Codeigniter`

It returns an error

```
Operation CREATE USER failed for 'agit****'@'localhost'
```

I have deleted the user from the `mysql.user` and tried again.

```
DROP USER 'agit****'@'localhost';
```

I have also tried

```
DROP USER 'agit****'@'%';
```

and

```
DELETE FROM `mysql.user` WHERE `user` LIKE 'agit****';
```

The user got deleted and then I executed the following query:

```
flush privileges;
```

and restarted the MySQL server. But no use.

I have tried to create the same user from command line, and it returns the following error code

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for
```

*Server details and version numbers*

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.45                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.5.45                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86                          |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> Note: This error occurs only when I try to create a user which existed already.
>
> New users can be added without any issue
>
> I have confirmed that the User got deleted from the MySQL.User table before creating the user account again.

Comment: *This error occurs only when I try to create a user which existed already.* Look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.user` - you will see that `(host,user)` is a primary key. That is why user creation for existing user@host fails - it is common duplicate violation.

Comment: @Akina, But I have deleted that user from the mysql.user table. So I should be able to add that user again, right?

Comment: If the user is deleted (check it by `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;`) and privileges are flushed then you may re-create it. But if the user exists I'd prefer `ALTER USER`.

Comment: Even after deleting the user from mysql.user, `select * from mysql.user where user = 'xxxx' and Host = 'localhost'` returns non-empty result. That's the issue. Is there anything to do differently on Windows Server/MySQL ?

Comment: *Even after deleting the user from mysql.user* Never alter system data directly! this may give unpredictable result. Use according query. PS. Now I'd recommend to restart MySQL service then alter user.